# How can I create a keyboard shortcut to perform a specific action on a case?

Tags: case

I frequently write case comments to support cases.  Is there an easy way to bind a shortcut key to the "New Case Comment" action within the console view  (without custom apex code)?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up keyboard shortcuts in the service console using point-and-click: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_setup_keyboard_shortcuts.htm&language=en